# How to check null condition for all the array items using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code like this:

```
BenefitValue = premiumResponseMessage.results[0].subItems[0]
                    .profiles[0].subItems[0].profiles[0].subItems[0].profiles[0]
                     .subItems[0].profiles[index].values[0]
```

Value assigned here is returned from some service. My question is I need to check each item for null before using it. How could it be achieved with minimal lines of code using LINQ?

Comment: Why is the amount of lines so important for you? You should not count lines but care about readability.

Comment: Is premiumResponseMessage of `dynamic` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider what Andre Snede Hansen wrote. It seems what you need here is sum type of recursion.

Regardless of that, your linq query would look something like that:

```
BenefitValue = from message in premiumResponseMessage.Reuslts.Take(1)
               where message != null
               from subItem1 in message.SubItems.Take(1)
               where subItem1 != null
               from profile1 in subItem1.Profiles.Take(1)
               where profile1 != null
               from subItem2 in profile1.SubItems.Take(1)
               where subItem2 != null
               ... etc.. etc
```

As you can see, this is still ugly as hell. Consider use recursive function, to retrieve the value X level deep into profiles

```
private BenefitValueType GetValueForProfile(SubItemType item, int level, int index)
{
    if ((item == null) || (item.Profiles[0] == null))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (level == 0)
    {
        return item.Profiles[index] != null
               ? item.Profiles[index].Value[0]
               : null;
    }
    else
    {
        return GetValueForProfile(item.Profiles[0].SubItems[0], level - 1, index);
    }
}
```

Notice that I didn't tested the code, neither did parameter validation...

Comment: Recursion is the way to go, and I was about to give a similar answer, but this solves it in a neat way.

Answer (score 2):

You should never ever do what you are trying to do. You are breaking the [`Law of Demeter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

3 levels down, and you would be stretching it, but your 10 amount of levels is just really really bad.

If you really must, then break it into small functions instead.
I see that subItems and Profiles repeat itself.

And to explain "levels":
This would be three levels:

```
                                    //1          2           3
BenefitValue = premiumResponseMessage.results[0].subItems[0].profiles[0];
```

Yours is 10 levels deep:

```
                                    //1          2           3          ....
BenefitValue = premiumResponseMessage.results[0].subItems[0].profiles[0].subItems[0].profiles[0].subItems[0].profiles[0].subItems[0].profiles[index].values[0]
```

Comment: Sorry I dint get what does that X amount of levels mean?

Comment: Every you retrieving another profile, you diving another "levlel"... Doing so more than 3 times, is a really bad practice, and you should consider more general solution (meaning, a solution to retrieve the profile X levels deep, instead of getting that profile in a hard coded fashion).

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz Exactly, well said :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/04/checking_for_possibly_null_values_in_linq.html) a few ways to check for null values by using LINQ.
But I think THIS might be the one you need (first example from the link above):

```
var titleless = items.Where(x => x.Title == null);
```

Answer (score -1):

the fastest way to check them all , You can use Try , Catch (NullReferenceException)

Comment: Exceptions are used to deal with unexpected conditions. If one of the expected possible values for an expression is null, then throwing an exception is bad solution. Moreover, it's inefficient and expansive.

Comment: Thank you for your comment

1) I think using recursion for more 8 levels is very expensive although it is a smart solution

2) I think convert all the null checking to the LINQ compiler specially if it is LINQ to a party like SQL or XML will be very expensive also

3) IF Exceptions are only meant for generic conditions , what is the use of specific exceptions , I know The EXCEPTION handling is not best for this case we know the logic specifically , but u have to consider cleaner, shorter and quicker idea

Comment: Recursion isn't necessarily expansive (with tail call optimization). I have no idea what is the LINQ compiler, but checking nulls in the DB would be generally less expensive. And I didn't said exceptions have to be general, but they should be used for unexpected conditions (like getting null in a method which in its design does not support nulls). Not for expected ones.